# VGAM percentile curve plot in R

Tags: r, curve-fitting, quantile, vgam

I am running following code from help files of VGAM:

```
library(VGAM)
fit4 <- vgam(BMI ~ s(age, df = c(4, 2)), lms.bcn(zero = 1), data = bmi.nz, trace = TRUE)
qtplot(fit4, percentiles = c(5,50,90,99), main = "Quantiles", las = 1, xlim = c(15, 90), ylab = "BMI", lwd = 2, lcol = 4)
```

[image]

How can I just prevent putting points on the plot so that the graph shows only percentile curves? Is there some option in qtplot where I can suppress points on this graph, so that I do not need to resort to long ggplot route as done on this page: [Percentiles from VGAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27547093/percentiles-from-vgam) ? In my earlier question there were other issues also so this point got ignored. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `qtplot` help page so I went to the package help Index and saw `qtplot.lmscreg` listed. It had a 'pcol.arg' to control points color so I set it to "transparent":

```
qtplot(fit4, percentiles = c(5,50,90,99), main = "Quantiles", las = 1, 
            xlim = c(15, 90), ylab = "BMI", lwd = 2, lcol = 4, 
            pcol.arg="transparent")
```

[image]

Comment: I am surprised they did not keep the option of not putting points on plot. Thanks.

Comment: I was puzzled about that as well. Also puzzled by no help page for a generic function. The class of the fit4 object did not match any of the qtplot methods in the Index so I just took a guess that since you were making it with lms.bcn that the nearest match to a method name might have a listing for parameters.

Comment: Please help me in another question on vgam: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27558687/how-to-suppress-vgam-loglikelihood-output-in-r

Comment: You should be embarrassed.

Comment: I had definitely tried this option, but at that time it did not work. I may have misspelled something. I have deleted that question.